# Adding a computer player to TicTacToe Java application?

Tags: java

How would I turn player 2 into a computer generated answer rather than another input. Selections by computer can be completely random as long as they follow the game rules and select an open space.

Also I want to keep the basic structure of my existing code...just need to turn one player into a computer generated selection. The selection does not need to be best choice just a valid one.

Don't want the answer just a place to start without destroying what I have...Any help please.

```
package tictactoe;


import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe
{
private final int BOARDSIZE = 3; // size of the board
private enum Status { WIN, DRAW, CONTINUE }; // game states
private char[][] board; // board representation
private boolean firstPlayer; // whether it's player 1's move
private boolean gameOver; // whether game is over

// Constructor
public TicTacToe()
{
  board = new char[ BOARDSIZE ][ BOARDSIZE ];
  firstPlayer = true;
  gameOver = false;
} // end Constructor

// start game
public void play()
{
  Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
  int row; // row for next move
  int column; // column for next move

  System.out.println( "Player X's turn." );

  while ( !gameOver )
  {
     char player = ( firstPlayer ? 'X' : 'O' );

     // player's turn
     do
     {
        System.out.printf(
           "Player %c: Enter row ( 0, 1 or 2 ): ", player );
        row = input.nextInt();
        System.out.printf(
           "Player %c: Enter column ( 0, 1 or 2 ): ", player );
        column = input.nextInt();
     } while ( !validMove( row, column ) );

     board[ row ][ column ] = player;

     firstPlayer = !firstPlayer;

     printBoard();
     printStatus( player );
  } // end while
} // end method play

// show game status in status bar
private void printStatus( int player )
{
  Status status = gameStatus();

  // check game status
  switch ( status )
  {
     case WIN:
        System.out.printf( "Player %c wins.", player );
        gameOver = true;
        break;
     case DRAW:  
        System.out.println( "Game is a draw." );
        gameOver = true;
        break;
     case CONTINUE:  
        if ( player == 'X' )
           System.out.println( "Player O's turn." );
        else
           System.out.println( "Player X's turn." );
        break;
  } // end switch
} // end method printStatus

// get game status
private Status gameStatus()
{   
  int a;

  // check for a win on diagonals
  if ( board[ 0 ][ 0 ] != 0 && board[ 0 ][ 0 ] == board[ 1 ][ 1 ] &&
     board[ 0 ][ 0 ] == board[ 2 ][ 2 ] )
     return Status.WIN;
  else if ( board[ 2 ][ 0 ] != 0 && board[ 2 ][ 0 ] == 
     board[ 1 ][ 1 ] && board[ 2 ][ 0 ] == board[ 0 ][ 2 ] )
     return Status.WIN;

  // check for win in rows
  for ( a = 0; a < 3; a++ )
     if ( board[ a ][ 0 ] != 0 && board[ a ][ 0 ] == 
          board[ a ][ 1 ] && board[ a ][ 0 ] == board[ a ][ 2 ] )
        return Status.WIN;

  // check for win in columns
  for ( a = 0; a < 3; a++ )
     if ( board[ 0 ][ a ] != 0 && board[ 0 ][ a ] == 
          board[ 1 ][ a ] && board[ 0 ][ a ] == board[ 2 ][ a ] )
        return Status.WIN;

  // check for a completed game
  for ( int r = 0; r < 3; r++ )
     for ( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
        if ( board[ r ][ c ] == 0 )
           return Status.CONTINUE; // game is not finished

  return Status.DRAW; // game is a draw
} // end method gameStatus

// display board
public void printBoard() 
{
  System.out.println( " _______________________ " );

  for ( int row = 0; row < BOARDSIZE; row++ )
  {
     System.out.println( "|       |       |       |" );

     for ( int column = 0; column < BOARDSIZE; column++ )
        printSymbol( column, board[ row ][ column ] );

     System.out.println( "|_______|_______|_______|" );
  } // end for
} // end method printBoard

// print moves
private void printSymbol( int column, char value )
{
  System.out.printf( "|   %c   ", value );

  if ( column == 2 )
     System.out.println( "|" );
} // end method printSymbol

// validate move
private boolean validMove( int row, int column )
{
  return row >= 0 && row < 3 && column >= 0 && column < 3 &&
     board[ row ][ column ] == 0;
} // end method validMove
 } // end class TicTacToe
```

Comment: If this were my code, I'd start over with the idea of refactoring everything and trying to create distinct objects each with its own responsibility including a game object, player object, computer player object... Divide and conquer.

Comment: I have to use this basic structure for a project I'm working on...

Answer (score 0):

First, you're going to be modifying the `do-while` in `play()` to alternate between asking the user, and picking the move for the computer.

If you just want a *random* move, you'll find the Java class `Random` useful. Create an instance once outside your loops.

```
Random random = new Random();
```

Now, you can ask for a random integer in the range [0,2] with:

```
int row = random.nextInt(3);
int col = random.nextInt(3);
```

Check the `board` to see if that spot is filled. If it is, you'll need to pick a different one.

If you wanted to find the *best* move, you could use the [minimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) algorithm. It searches through a tree of possible moves made by the two players, presuming that each will play his or her best.

Answer (score 0):

At the point where you ask the user for the row and column of their move, replace that with a call to a method of another object that represents either a player (in which case it will simply prompt for the input, and then return it to the caller), or a computer player (in which case it will calculate the move by whatever means you determine, and return it).

That method will need to have the board passed to it. The player class can ignore it, but the computer player will need it to decide on its move.

You will also want to create some sort of `Move` class so you can pass the move (the row and column) back as a single return value.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public int[] autoPlay()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int randomValue[] = new int[2];
        do{
            randomValue[0] = rnd.nextInt(3);
            randomValue[1] = rnd.nextInt(3);
        } while ( !validMove( randomValue[0], randomValue[1] ) );
        return randomValue;
    }

// start game
    public void play()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        int row; // row for next move
        int column; // column for next move

        System.out.println( "Player X's turn." );

        while ( !gameOver )
        {
            char player = ( firstPlayer ? 'X' : 'O' );

            // player's turn
            do
            {
                if(player == 'X') {
                    System.out.printf(
                            "Player %c: Enter row ( 0, 1 or 2 ): ", player);
                    row = input.nextInt();
                    System.out.printf(
                            "Player %c: Enter column ( 0, 1 or 2 ): ", player);
                    column = input.nextInt();
                }else
                {
                    int array[] = autoPlay();
                    row = array[0];
                    column = array[1];
                }
            } while ( !validMove( row, column ) );

            board[ row ][ column ] = player;

            firstPlayer = !firstPlayer;

            printBoard();
            printStatus( player );
        } // end while
    } // end method play
```